# How to loop over delete

Tags: sql, firebird, sql-delete, firebird2.5

I wonder whether and how one can loop over the result(s) of a `delete` statement.

The `delete` statement is able to return values of the deleted record:

> *[Firebird 2.5 Language Reference](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-delete.html)*
>
> ```
> DELETE
>   FROM {target} [[AS] alias]
>   [WHERE {search-conditions | CURRENT OF cursorname}]
>   [PLAN plan_items]
>   [ORDER BY sort_items]
>   [ROWS <m> [TO <n>]]
>   [RETURNING <returning_list> [INTO <variables>]]
>
> <m>, <n>         ::=  Any expression evaluating to an integer.
> <returning_list> ::=  ret_value [, ret_value ...]
> <variables>      ::=  :varname [, :varname ...]
> ```

But using the `returning` syntax, a `delete` with more than one result record gives me:

> multiple rows in singleton select.

A block statement like such

```
EXECUTE BLOCK
RETURNS (
  ADSREF TYPE OF DMN_REFID)
AS
begin
  for
    delete from m_s_ad_memo
      returning ADSREF into :adsref
  do
    suspend;
end
```

returns the following error message:

> Invalid token.
>   Dynamic SQL Error.
>   SQL error code = -104.
>   Token unknown - line 7, column 5.
>   delete.

So, is this possible at all?

Could it work with a surrounding `for select ... do`-loop and a cursor?
How would such approach look like?
I haven't worked with cursors, yet.

Comment: Two links to examples of "working with cursors" are at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45373980/976391 - but cursors can be very slow in FB3, they still are finding performance bugs in them in 3.01, 3.02, ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not.

> But using the returning syntax, a delete with more than one result record gives me:
> multiple rows in singleton select.

Exactly.

INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/UPDATE-OR-INSERT are considered Stored Procedures Call class of statements when executed with RETURNING clause, not Query class of statements.

That means they do not return some "resultset" of many different rows, but they return a set of scalar Parameters/Fields.

And you can not "loop" over the set that contains no rows at all.

---

The documentation by your link claims that

> **RETURNING**
>
> A `DELETE` statement removing **at most one row** may optionally include a RETURNING clause in order to return values from the deleted row.

Emphasis is from the documentation itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE NEW_PROCEDURE
RETURNS (
    OUT VARCHAR(10))
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE ID INTEGER;
DECLARE VARIABLE TEXT VARCHAR(10);
BEGIN
  FOR SELECT xxx.id
  FROM xxx
  WHERE xxx.id < 5 --some condition
  INTO :ID DO
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM xxx
    WHERE xxx.id = :ID
    RETURNING xxx.name INTO :TEXT;    /*this is optional (you could select this 
                                        text in up select statement*/

    OUT = :ID || ' ' || :TEXT;

    SUSPEND;
  END
END
```

Comment: one can also do without `:ID` variable executing inner `DELETE` with "WHERE CURRENT OF *CURSOR*" clause, But in Firebird 3 cursors are often very slow.

Comment: @Arioch'The Didn't know this! Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: open www.translate.ru and scan through http://www.sql.ru/forum/1269227 and http://www.sql.ru/forum/1233785